# Create an incremental placeholder in NHaml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhaml

What I want to reach is a way to add a script and style placeholder in my master.
They will include my initial site.css and jquery.js files.
Each haml page or partial can then add their own required files to those placeholders.

Currently I'm creating two strings in my master that I append to in my views.
This results in an ugly and error prone rendering.
Is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to implement
>   this?

Yes. [This is how I did it](http://dnagir.blogspot.com/2009/07/nhaml-scripts-and-styles-code-block.html) and so far it works great for me.

Comment: Thx. I saw your post earlier. I don't feel comfortable with limiting the number of css and js files, but re-reading your solution gave me some hints I will investigate.